# NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter iOS 8. Notification is not being delivered to one of observers

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

Prior iOS 8 all works fine. The problem is:
I have two observers in different classes:

class1:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishParseUser:)
                                             name:USERS_LOADED_NOTIFICATION_ID object:nil];
```

class2:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishParseUser:)
                                                 name:USERS_LOADED_NOTIFICATION_ID object:nil];
```

and notification is posted in some other place:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=id,first_name,last_name,picture.type(small)" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:USERS_LOADED_NOTIFICATION_ID object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: currentUser, @"user", friends, @"friends", nil]];
    } else {
        // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
        // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
    }
}];
```

addObserver method is called for both of mentioned classes, however notification is being delivered just to one observer. If I delete this observer(which receives the notification), then another one receives the notification.
Prior to iOS 8 both observers receive the notification.

Can you, please, help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer.
There is another way in iOS 8 to register for receiving remote notifications. I get nil for device token and app break on line:

```
NSDictionary *item = @{UID_ID : sCurrentUserId, @"deviceToken": appDelegate.deviceToken, @"handle": @"", @"friends": friends};
```

and second observer never receives notification.

Answer (score -1):

You need to register your NSNotifications to work on iOS 8 and later but don't need to register if your iOS version is less than iOS 8.
**Use Following Code**

```
 NSArray *vComp = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 8) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground categories:nil]];

}
```

happy Coding

Comment: i suppose that was about Local notification... Sorry

Comment: But might help someone stuck in this Problem.